# Cannot parse kml file to be treated as xml

Tags: node.js, kml

I want to parse a kml file to be treated like a xml file :

```
var parser = require('xml2json');
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var xml = "D:/Axes2019.kml";
    var json = parser.toJson(xml);
    console.log("to json -> %s", json);
    res.render("index");
});
```

At runtime I get `There are errors in your xml file: not well-formed (invalid token)`

Here is the kml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Schema name="Axes_2K19" id="Axes_2K19">
    <SimpleField name="Name" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Denomin" type="string"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
<Folder><name>Axes_2K19</name>
  <Placemark>
    <name>9O_6</name>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData>
        <SimpleData name="Denomin">Antanimena</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>47.5282959843938,-18.8881931524494 47.5273060204005,-18.8883147269749 47.525771678897,-18.8898762249651 47.525391488082,-18.8909217497064 47.5247125759123,-18.8915497434633 47.5244138545577,-18.8919299342784 47.5243188068539,-18.8924866422575 47.5259255656555,-18.8935536658841 47.5268466231657,-18.8952758397545 47.5265207453242,-18.8961312690883 47.5276816851343,-18.8957442891516 47.5279871956107,-18.8964978816599 47.529947,-18.89907 47.52965,-18.901435 47.5292802275261,-18.9017841358174 47.5286065539348,-18.9019002864366 47.5276076586099,-18.9018770563128 47.5269339850186,-18.9021906629845 47.5268062193375,-18.9027481859566 47.526667,-18.903358 47.526247,-18.903399 47.525913,-18.903094 47.525489,-18.903003 47.524572,-18.902694 47.523774,-18.902588 47.523368,-18.9026 47.522878,-18.902871 47.522666,-18.903034 47.5223273311563,-18.9027936605133 47.521073,-18.901036 47.520669,-18.900556 47.518254,-18.89732 47.5166722429164,-18.8951662207165 47.516752829692,-18.8950896025168 47.5168139317873,-18.8943258263259 47.5166917275968,-18.8930121312776 47.5173638506447,-18.8917595383246 47.5187879970001,-18.8904753419999 47.516371167,-18.887820824 47.5151030731197,-18.8858937371787 47.5153169304532,-18.8838162659395 47.5165084213109,-18.8805396660807 47.5159890535012,-18.8784851081272 47.5159886221055,-18.8784787989658 47.5193198602536,-18.8783563269751 47.521029,-18.877701 47.5222222097789,-18.8787229395467 47.5236810223034,-18.8789367968802 47.526064004019,-18.8796089199281 47.529757529473,-18.8805918742828 47.5292090646449,-18.8815425466514 47.5290563094068,-18.8836505689382 47.5292090646449,-18.8857662289869 47.5285674926446,-18.8872937813686 47.5282959843938,-18.8881931524494</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
  </Placemark>
  ...
  </Folder>
</Document></kml>
```

So how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

I checked your sample KML for XML and KML Schema validity, and it looked fine to me.  Maybe your parser wants more of the namespaces defined?  See below for what I usually include at the top of my KMLs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
...
</kml>
```

Or maybe some of the rest of your file (which you replaced with "..." contains XML errors? Make sure all your IDs are valid too (start with a letter, no forbidden characters, etc.).

Comment: I still get the error even if I included your xmlns suggestions and even if I reduce the kml content to a single Placemark tag which is the first one.